# Multiply each item in a dataframe by a power of a scalar

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to multiply each item in a dataframe by lambda to the power of its index + 1.

The formula i am trying to implement:

[image]

My code looks like this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ML_Flos_file_name = r'S&P 500 Vol.xlsx' 
xls_flos = pd.ExcelFile(ML_Flos_file_name)
data = pd.read_excel(xls_flos, 'ES',skiprows=6, usecols=['Date', 'PX_LAST'])
data['pr'] = data['PX_LAST']/data['PX_LAST'].shift(-1)
data['lr'] = np.log(data['pr'])
newdata = data.head(125)
```

How do i do the lambda multiplier?

Comment: Could you provide an example in input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your DataFrame contains:

```
     r
0  100
1  120
2  140
3  160
```

(the most important thing is that the index contains consecutive numbers
starting from *0*).

Let's set the lambda value to *1.2*.

Then, to compute *lambda ^ index*, you can run:

```
df.index.to_series().rpow(lam)
```

getting:

```
0    1.000
1    1.200
2    1.440
3    1.728
```

And to multiply a column (assume *r*) by this value and save the
result in another column, say *rPwr*, run:

```
df['rPwr'] = df.r * df.index.to_series().rpow(lam)
```

Now *df* contains:

```
     r    rPwr
0  100  100.00
1  120  144.00
2  140  201.60
3  160  276.48
```

Or maybe you want only the sum of what was saved in *rPwr* column?
If this is the case, you can do without creating a new column.
Just run:

```
rPwrSum = (df.r * df.index.to_series().rpow(lam)).sum()
```

getting:

```
722.0799999999999
```